# Capybara Error Handling Hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Capybara with Cukes to test a non-local Rails app that relies on alot of API/Services. As such, there are many times that the API requests times out. The app has a global timeout exception catch, that the user is displayed with a specific prompt that asks them "to click here to try again" and it continues that previous failed request.

Let's say my step definition was as follows:

```
When(/^I navigate to the user page$/) do
  visit homepage
  click_link "Dashboard"
  page.should have_content "Dashboard Content"
  click_link "User"
  current_path.should == "/users"
end
```

However, the timeout can occur at any given step in the definition, such as after clicking the link to Dashboard, or after User. So basically it can fail on a find (click_link) or an assertion, due to the fact it won't be able to continue its action since the "timeout page" is currently being displayed.

What I was trying to figure out is how to create an Around hook for my Capybara that essentially will rescue any thrown exception, check if the current page is the timeout page and if so click on the retry link on the page, and then continue from the action that resulted in the exception.

Does such a concept exist?